# How to transition away from deprecated TestBed.get()

Tags: angular, jasmine

Using Angular 14.

We have a couple of test suites, which need to dynamically change the parameters on `ActivatedRoute`, so they do

```
TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute).paramMap = of(convertToParamMap({
  < new parameters here >
}));
```

which is working fine, however the `get` has a strike-through marking indicating that it is deprecated from Angular 9 onwards, with a hint that you should use `inject` instead.

But whereas `TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute).paramMap` is valid code, the returned `paramMap` reference becomes read-only, and so the assignment is not.

What's the correct approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's javascript, don't sweat it.

```js
Object.assign(TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute), {
  paramMap: of(convertToParamMap({}))
});
```